# mysql 8 не получается установить пароль

Tags: mysql, ubuntu

Какая то проблема с установкой mysql 8. После удачной установки запускаю mysql_secure_installation. Прохожу все пункты устанавливаю пароль в LOW и ставлю ifqnfy123 и все равно с этим паролем не пускает туда. Постоянно пишет Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'. Я все перепроверил. Пароль верный. Что это может быть?

Comment: Как именно логинитесь?

Comment: *Прохожу все пункты устанавливаю пароль в LOW и ставлю ifqnfy123 и все равно с этим паролем не пускает туда. Постоянно пишет Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'.* Во-первых, не обрезайте сообщения об ошибках. Во-вторых, какому именно юзеру устанавливаете пароль - случайно, не `'root'@'%'`?

Comment: Да руту, уже разобрался спасибо!). В 5.7 было гораздо проще с этим, а в 8 версии лучше зайти под sudo mysql  и завести отдельного пользователя.